# How to pass variable to joomla language files (.ini)

Tags: email, variables, joomla, ini

i want to send email messages to different users. each email messages contain user name and other user details.  i stored this email content on language files. so i want to pass users name variables to language files? or any other way to send messages with user names?
my code is

```
      foreach($rowEmails as $userDonerEmail){
    JUtility::sendMail($fromEmail, $fromName, $userDonerEmail,     JText::sprintf('JD_SUBJECT_DONER_WATERWELL', $rowCampaign->title), JText::sprintf('JD_BODY_DONER_WATERWELL', $rowCampaign->title, $rowCampaign->name), 1);
          }

          JUtility::sendMail($fromEmail, $fromName, $rowCampaign->email,  JText::sprintf('JD_SUBJECT_CREATOR_WATERWELL'), JText::sprintf('JD_BODY_CREATOR_WATERWELL',     $rowCampaign->name, $rowCampaign->title, $newWellAmount, JURI::base().'index.php?link
_here'.$rowCampaign->id), 1);
```

please help me. thanks.

Comment: What happens when you do that?

Comment: only 'JD_SUBJECT_DONER_WATERWELL' sending, no content @David

Comment: a bit more context would be nice. where are you doing this JText::sprintf - do you have other calls to JText methods there? Are they working as expected? Do you have the JD_SUBJECT... in a language file which is currently loaded (check via "debug language" in the settings)

Comment: more conetnt added... please check @nyarlathotep

Comment: please read my comment again, not just the first sentence

Comment: yes, i also used JText methods in other places, those also not working. how can i check that using language debug mode on in settings @nyarlathotep...

Answer (score 2):

This is how it should look like:

in **PHP**:

```
<?php echo JText::sprintf('SOME_TEXT', $var1, $var2, $var3); ?>
```

in ***.ini** file:

```
SOME_TEXT="Variables are: %s, %s, %s";
```